# Having some CSS problems

Tags: javascript, css, html, slick.js

I've been trying to get a modal to pop up above the rest of my content for a while and can't seem to make it happen. All other modals on my page work, except for one. When I click the image that I'm trying to get to pop up, The modal appears to fill the slick-list section, but not the rest of the page. The carousel that I'm using is called Slick Slider.

See photos for what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PlXS.jpg

As you can see, everything within the slick-list section darkens, but a modal doesn't appear. Also, clicking anywhere on the page, including the dark section does not close the modal like it does with the other modals. Additionally, even though all CSS settings are identical across every modal on the page, the one that's giving me issues appears much darker than the others...I'm not sure if this is a clue or not.

Things I've tried:
changing the z-index
changing the position
changing the display

I am seriously out of ideas guys! My little modal seems stuck in a box forever :(

PUG

```
 .slick-carousel
  div
    .item
      img(src="images/test2.jpg").item-trigger
      .item-modal
        .item-modal-content
        span.item-close-button ×
        h1 Item!
```

My CSS

```
.item-modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
  z-index: 999999;
}
.item-modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  width: 24rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
.item-close-button {
  float: right;
  width: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.item-close-button:hover {
  background-color: darkgray;
}
.item-show-modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1.0);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}
```

Slick CSS

```
.slick-list
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    /* made overflow visible to show box shadows around whole poster */
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: People would be much more willing to help if you narrowed down the problem and had a minimal working code example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. The title of the question should also be more specific.

Comment: I've never used slick-slider, but if the modal element is anything like every other modal element in every other css framework, it should be placed as close as possible to the root `<body`> element, or at least somewhere it isn't constrained (like inside a slider div). From the picture it looks to be that way, so maybe that's the key.